# tournament selection in genetic algorithm

Tags: genetic-algorithm

I do this procedure for tournament selection in a genetic algorithm:

> choose k random individuals from population & select two best individuals among these k individuals to be parents.

is it correct?

Comment: 'select two best individuals'? Not sure of this. Firstly your sample is a subset = 'k' values. You have to choose based on gender and best traits.

Comment: ofcourse I choose based on fitness values,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Considering that you are using Fitness criteria, here a pseudo-code that can help you.

```
func tournament_selection(pop, k):
best = null
for i=1 to k
    ind = pop[random(1, N)]
    if (best == null) or fitness(ind) > fitness(best)
        best = ind
return best
```

So basically the approach you are following is fine. Though there is a lot more to it like crossover and stuff, I guess you have taken care of it.

Reference link with a great solution- [Tournament Selection in Genetic Algorithms](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/14758/tournament-selection-in-genetic-algorithms)

---

To extend this,
use another variable 'better'.
Do something like-

```
better = best
best = ind
```

and while returning, return an object that is a pair of these 2 variables.

Or another approach would be - calling the same instance of function twice, it would return BEST and BEST-1. Some tweaks in code is needed to handle the Sample.

PS: This may not be an optimal approach.

Comment: as you know this pseudo-code returns one individual (the best one). I have to have two individuals to form parents to get offspring! (I mean a pair of individuals)

Comment: can I get two best individuals from these k random induviduals to form parents?

Comment: Yes. By calling the same tournament_selection() twice, you will get Best and Best-1 options from the set of options you have.

Or another approach is, by maintaining another variable called 'better' and playing with the code.
Inside the if condition write- better = best; best = ind;

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Updating the answer to add more clarity to the code.

Comment: thanks, one more question: what is the optimal and usual value of selective pressure in tournament selection? I mean how many percent of best  members of the current generation should   propagate to the next generation?

Comment: That % varies from problem to problem. If you ask me, with my knowledge and understanding your scenario, 20-30% would be ideal. 20% would be better. Check it out with different values and analyse what suits better.

Answer (score 5):

**Tournament Selection:**

- Tournament selection is a method of selecting an individual from a population of individuals.
- Tournament selection involves running several "tournaments" among a few individuals chosen at random from the population.
- The winner of each tournament (the one with the best fitness) is selected for crossover.
- When the tournament size is smaller, Tournament selection also gives a chance to all individuals to be selected and thus it preserves diversity, although keeping diversity may degrade the convergence speed.
- But if the tournament size is larger, weak individuals have a smaller chance to be selected causes loss of diversity .

**PseudoCode:**

```
choose k (the tournament size) individuals from the population at random
choose the best individual from pool/tournament with probability p
choose the second best individual with probability p*(1-p)
choose the third best individual with probability p*((1-p)^2)
and so on...
```

Deterministic tournament selection selects the best individual (when p = 1) in any tournament. A 1-way tournament (k = 1) selection is equivalent to random selection. The chosen individual can be removed from the population that the selection is made from if desired, otherwise individuals can be selected more than once for the next generation. In comparison with the (stochastic) fitness proportionate selection method, tournament selection is often implemented in practice due to its lack of stochastic noise.

**Tournament Selection in MatLab:**

```
Matepool=randi(PopLength,PopLength,2);%%select two individuals randomly for tournament and chooose the one with best fitness value
%% number of tournament is equal to the number of population size
for i=1:PopLength
    if Fitness(Matepool(i,1))>= Fitness(Matepool(i,2))
        SelectedPop(i,1:IndLength)=CurrentPop(Matepool(i,1),1:IndLength);
    else
        SelectedPop(i,1:IndLength)=CurrentPop(Matepool(i,2),1:IndLength);
    end
end
```

Comment: Nice copy-paste of the Wikipedia page, Setu (pseudo code part).

Answer (score 1):

Tournament selection is one of the many techniques used for selection of parents for the crossover like the roulette wheel selection. I will also like to point out that for selection besides fitness, experience/age of the classifier should also be considered for selection. Beta be the factor for contribution by fitness and 1-beta is for the experience. The code snippet is in java.

```
  ArrayList<Genotype> Crossover (ArrayList Population){
  ArrayList<Genotype> selected= ArrayList<Genotype>();
  Geneotype best=NULL, second_best=NULL;
  for(int i=0; i<k;i++){
    int prob= Math.random()+Population.size(); // generate a number between 0 and last index of arraylist
      if(best==NULL || best.fitness<Population.get(prob).fitness)
        best= Population.get(prob);
      else{
        if(second_best.fitness<Population.get(prob).fitness)
           best= Population.get(prob);
      }
  Population.remove(prob); // Wil not affect the actual population because parameters are pass by value not reference  
  selected.add(best);
  selected.add(second_best);
  return selected;  
}
```